# Aptana studio with file lost

Tags: aptana

I did a project with my friend using aptana sync by FTP.
Today when i save file on FTP my connection lost.i open file.php again There are 455 line from 600 line.i didn't sync with git and my friend don't open aptana yet.Can i recover it? Have a temp file or history? ;(

Comment: I doubt it. Check if there are any backup/tempfiles in the folder where that file resided.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Eclipse Local History as your first step: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm

Answer (score 0):

On linux I was able to recover the file from `/tmp` folder (it has a gibberish name there so you have to digg a little). hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Never say never, I just lost my 2 days work after out-of-mind checkout with lot of ucommitted changes and ended up here... I couldn't get it from local history in Aptana, /tmp was empty but I could find all the files in .metadata hidden dir in workspace. I guess git makes the local history act differently in Aptana itself, but it's still stored here `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history`